# Get the distinct of two columns that are the reverse of each other in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, distinct

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I can't seem to find it anywhere else.

I have a table like so:

```
column1 column2 column3
entry 1 A   B
ENTRY 2 A   C
ENTRY 3 B   C
ENTRY 1 B   A
ENTRY 2 C   A
ENTRY 3 C   B
```

The table I'm using has more columns but the idea is the same.

Is there an easy clean way to get the distinct entries (i.e. I'm  only interested in bringing back Entry 1 once, not twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select distinct t1.Column1, 
  case when t1.Column2 < t2.Column2 then t1.Column2 else t2.Column2 end as Column2,   
  case when t1.Column3 > t2.Column3 then t1.Column3 else t2.Column3 end as Column3  
from myTable t1
inner join myTable t2 on t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 
     and t1.column2 = t2.column3;
```

EDIT: A simpler one:

```
Select t1.* 
  from myTable t1
  inner join myTable t2 on t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 
       and t1.Column2 = t2.Column3
  where t1.column2 < t1.column3
```

EDIT2: And if you want to also return rows where there is no such dupes:

```
Select t1.* 
from myTable t1
left join myTable t2 on t1.Column1 = t2.Column1 
   and t1.Column2 = t2.Column3
where t1.column2 < t1.column3 or t2.COlumn1 is null;
```

Answer (score 5):

If columns 2 and 3 contain "reverse duplicates" that you want to hide, you will have to decide what ordering you want to see:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM aTable
WHERE column2 <= column3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` to find the duplicates and then `<` (or `>`) to get one of the rows;

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.column1 = t1.column1 and
                    t2.column2 = t1.column3 and
                    t2.column3 = t1.column2
              ) and
      t.column1 < t.column2;
```

Comment: Did you mean `not exists` and `or`?

Comment: @WolfgangK . . . No.  The OP wants duplicates, but only wants one row with them.

Comment: ... ok, I didn't see (and still don't) that requirement. So you meant "You can use `exists`". :-)

Answer (score 1):

From your data I assumed, that each entry has the same `column1` value, if they are duplicate. Try:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM (
    SELECT column1,
           column2,
           column3,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2, column3) rn
    FROM MyTable
) a WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I your case you can use `distinct` with `outer apply`. in outer apply you can add `order by` that you need

```
select distinct
  t.column1, 
  r.column2,
  r.column3
from myTable t
outer apply (
  select top 1
    r.column2,
    r.column3
  from myTable as r
  where r.column1 = t.column1
) as r
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answer till now, will loose data for single combination entry. It is suppose to be below code

```
Select distinct t1.Column1, 
  case when t1.Column2 < t1.Column3 then t1.Column2 else t1.Column3 end as Column2,   
  case when t1.Column2 < t1.Column3 then t1.Column3 else t1.Column2 end as Column3  
from myTable t1
```